# How to Animate an arrow between to co ordinates on a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

Can some one please help me to animate the line joining two co ordinates on a leaflet map?

This is what I have right now:

[image: [1]]

I want the orange line to animate from one point to another. For example, a continues flow of arrow.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in those plugins:

- [Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim) to progressively display the orange line from one end to the other.
- [Leaflet Ant Path](https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/leaflet-ant-path) to fill the orange line with animated dashes that slide from one end to the other ([demo](http://rubenspgcavalcante.github.io/leaflet-ant-path/)).